# How do I resize my MySQL screen? (server 5.1)

Tags: mysql, screen

I created a table in MySQL (server 5.1), but my table has many columns so when I do a

```
SELECT * FROM my_table;
```

The columns end up overlapping each other, making it very confusing to read.

I tried maximizing the screen size, but it is still too small to fit the the entire table in one piece. There also seems to be no tool bar at the top of MySQL program.

Comment: Try `select * from mytable\G`

Comment: Yes! That was good enough. Thank you

Comment: Why you dont use phpmyadmin ?

Comment: I use MySql (server 5.1) as it's part of my school's curriculum.